# Meaning of '*' in CSS

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css: the meaning of * mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359201/css-the-meaning-of-mark)

What does `*` do in css? I saw some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329866/centering-elements-in-jquery-mobile) that contained it:

```
.center-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
.center-wrapper * {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Is this a typo?

Comment: I tired googling * css, * meaning css, css *, and css * symbol meaning, and none of them came up with results. Thats why I thought it was a typo

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`*` means ALL.

In this case it would be ALL the elements in `.center-wrapper`

Answer (score 5):

It's a wildcard, it matches every element.  So in your example, it means every element that's a descendant of elements with the "center-wrapper" class.

According to the official W3C docs, it's called a "universal selector", see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector:

> The universal selector, written as a
>   CSS qualified name [CSS3NAMESPACE]
>   with an asterisk (* U+002A) as the
>   local name, represents the qualified
>   name of any element type.

Answer (score 1):

- means everthing: every tag/element in document.

In this case `.center-wrapper *` everything under every element with center-wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

* is Universal selector.
`.center-wrapper *` select all descendant elements of `.center-wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means that the styles assigned to it must be applied to the whole page. It is not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It means it will select all elements within that portion of the DOM.