# CSS3 and html5 the meaning of * special character

Tags: css, css-selectors, special-characters, wildcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css: the meaning of * mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359201/css-the-meaning-of-mark)

What does the symbol `*` mean in CSS3. As used in a code;

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: `*` generally refers to all elements (or has css3 redefined it?)

Comment: @deceze it is a duplicate, but thanks for the answers...

Comment: @techfoobar: Nope. The CSS3 spec has, however, [added namespace-matching capabilities to it](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#univnmsp). But `*` itself remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- this refers to all the elements and this particular code will make all the element's margin and padding as 0

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a **reset style**. To cancel out differences in user agent/browser styles.

Comment: The `*` itself doesn't mean "reset" - it's a selector that matches all elements. In the example above, it's being used to set margin and padding on all elements to `0`.

Comment: @daGUY: I meant the whole thing. The usage of `*` with the particular  CSS.

Comment: I know, but the question was asking what the `*` meant in particular.

Answer (score 1):

[`*` is a general and CSS wildcard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Universal_selectors), the selector you show above selects all elements in a HTML document. It is commonly used in [reset stylesheets](http://www.cssreset.com/) and is sometimes referred to as a universal selector.